# Where (if there is) is the IEEE glossary newer than 1990?

Tags: testing, theory

I have been looking for some formal definitons but could not find any IEEE newer than 610, which is from 1990. Could you help me please?

Comment: http://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/610-1990.html - withdrawn standard. According to the tooltip there, that means both that it's not really a standard anymore, and that there is no superseding document.

Comment: I'm not sure why this question was being downvoted. On the surface, it seems like a normal resource request. However, searching for things like "software engineering glossary" or "software engineering dictionary" bring up references to the withdrawn IEEE Std 610-1990 or to the work of individual people that can't necessarily be considered canonical (and sometimes even disagree). Since it doesn't appear to be easy to use a search engine to find the answer, I don't see how this is a bad question.

Comment: Thank you. I have seen on the IEEE website that you can buy an access to that glossary of terms. And its pretty expensive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like [Mat says in his comment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/163366/where-if-there-is-is-the-ieee-glossary-newer-than-1990/163371#comment312650_163366), IEEE Standard 610-1990 has been withdrawn (effective April 20, 2001), which means that it is no longer maintained and the information may be obsolete or erroneous.

Although it's more than just a glossary of terms, the [Guide to the Software Engineering Body of Knowledge](http://www.computer.org/portal/web/swebok/home) ([free HTML format](http://www.computer.org/portal/web/swebok/htmlformat), paid PDF and dead-tree format) typically provides formal definitions for terms that relate to each knowledge area that come from widely accepted publications. However, this document does cite IEEE 610-1990 for some definitions. I would assume that even though 610-1990 might contain obsolete information, the selected definitions that come from this document are still valid (especially considering the final publication of the SWEBOK was 3 years about 610-1990 was withdrawn, which is sufficient time to update anything that could be considered obsolete).

Answer (score -2):

Yes, there is a better "IEEE glossary" than IEEE 610-1990. It's ISO/IEC/IEEE 24765:2010 Systems and software engineering -- Vocabulary. It can [be accessed through the IEEE Computer Society for free](http://pascal.computer.org/sev_display/index.action).

Comment: without an explanation, this answer may become useless in case if someone else posts an opposite opinion. For example, if someone posts a claim like _"there is nothing better than IEEE 610. Software and Systems Engineering Vocabulary is worse"_, how would this answer help reader to pick of two opposing opinions? Consider [edit]ing it into a better shape, to fit [answer] guidelines.